# Strapi add extra field in the relationship table

Tags: postgresql, strapi

I am using Strapi for my application. I am using Postgres as a database. There is user table. I want to create a Teams table linked with Team Leaders and Team Members related to users table. I added team name, team code, and Team Leaders(Relationship field -> Many to Many Relationship), Team members(Relationship field -> Many to Many Relationship)

After I did this, My table fields look like this,

```
Teams,
Id, name, code

teams_team_leaders__users_team_leaders
Id, Team id, User id

teams_team_members__users_teams
Id, Team Id, User id
```

But here I wanted to add one extra field (custom_role) in the `teams_team_leaders__users_team_leaders` and `teams_team_members__users_teams` table. Is there any way to add a new field/column into Relationship tables?